# Redirect remote file to another

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file

I'm using Windows 7, and I wanted to know how could I make it so that when my PC try's to connect to a defined remote file it will redirect it to another.

Example: `http://www.a.com/image.png` to `http://www.a.com/image_0.png`

I tried using the hosts file, but no, it won't redirect a specific file.
If would love to be able to do this without software, thanks.

Comment: What's the actual reason? And assuming that there was a way to do this, how would you be supposed to map one URL to another "without software", would Windows or your browser had to ask you every time for a redirection URL for every single request? (That would still require software, you know.)

Comment: Exactly. This is an XY problem. Instead of asking how to do this, it would make more sense to tell us what you are trying to achieve so we can give you the best solution. It is unlikely that the task you are asking us to help you to perform is the best solution for your problem.

Comment: @DesmondHume When he says without software, He probably means NATIVELY.  And, i'm sure you can't.  Privoxy might do it though, but even  if it does, it might be slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it natively.  Maybe FF has an extension.. But i'd guess Privoxy can do it. It's a web proxy, you typically run it locally, and it can rewrite webpages, and apparently also requests too.

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3495715&group_id=11118&atid=211118

http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#REDIRECT

Typical use: Redirect requests to other sites.

Effect:  Convinces the browser that the requested document has been moved to another location and the browser should get it from there.

(privoxy can be a bit fiddly though, and slow browsing down sometimes, and I can't test it at the moment)